# Why does this deref coercion fail when the expression is wrapped in a block?

Tags: syntax, rust, coercion

`String` implements `Deref<Target = str>`, which means that the following code compiles:

```
fn save(who: &str) {
    println!("I'll save you, {}!", who);
}

save(&String::from("Madoka"));
```

If I create a custom type that also implements `Deref<Target = str>`, then that works too:

```
struct Madoka;

impl Deref for Madoka {
    type Target = str;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        "Madoka"
    }
}

save(&Madoka);
```

Now, let's try coercing to another type -- say, `u32`. It seems to work as well:

```
fn reset(how: &u32) {
    println!("Reset {} times", how);
}

struct Homura;

impl Deref for Homura {
    type Target = u32;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &42
    }
}

reset(&Homura);
```

But when I wrap the expression in a block, it no longer compiles:

```
reset(&{ Homura });
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:14
   |
17 |     reset(&{ Homura });
   |              ^^^^^^ expected u32, found struct `main::Homura`
   |
   = note: expected type `u32`
              found type `main::Homura`
```

The weird thing is that the equivalent expression with `&str` compiles just fine:

```
save(&{ Madoka });  // OK
```

Why does the first expression fail to compile, but the second succeed?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19b7a96a8bcf4e4f9c21326e642026b7)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is, but you can make it work by using two ampersands: `reset(&&{Homura});` or putting the ampersand inside the block: `reset({&Homura});`

Comment: Usually in these situations I will say that it's a bug, and then @trentcl will explain how it's actually expected behaviour. With that in mind... I think it looks like a bug.

Comment: There seems to be something special about slices. If `&Deref::Target` is a slice then it works.

Comment: @PeterHall Sorry to disappoint, because I think this must be a bug. ;-)

Comment: It also works like these : `let h = &{Homura}; reset(h);` or  `reset(&*{Homura});`

Comment: I've filed an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57749).